# OpenLayers: Update tile layer regularly

Tags: openlayers

I'm building a map with OpenLayers that shows HERE Maps traffic information. This traffic information is provided as a transparent tile overlay and should be updated regularly (e.g. every five minutes) to show the user relevant information even if the map is open for a long time.

My current workaround is to change the URLs of the tiles by adding a timestamp, which eventually causes a reload:

```
const newUrl: string = LAYER_URL + "&timestamp=" + new Date().getTime();
layer.getSource().setUrl(newUrl);
```

I wonder if there is a better way in OpenLayers to update the tiles without having to assume that the tile server ignores the additional timestamp-parameter. Other attempts like calling `layer.changed()` or `layer.getSource().changed()` resulted in no effect.

Comment: `layer.getSource().setUrl(currentUrl);` would be sufficient to clear the OpenLayers cache.  The timestamp is usually added to override browser cache.

Comment: @Mike Thanks for the quick response! Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me. When I just re-set the same URL, no new tile requests appear in the network log. The browser cache shouldn't be the problem since the tiles have a max-age of a minute.

Comment: I've checked the source and `setUrl` results in a call to `setTileUrlFunction` which "prunes" the cache (it doesn't clear the current zoom level)
https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/src/ol/source/UrlTile.js
Resetting the tileLoadFunction clears the cache by calling `layer.getSource().tileCache.clear();` or if you don't want to use undocumented methods which might change in a future release you could use 
`layer.getSource().setTileLoadFunction(layer.getSource().getTileLoadFunction());`

Comment: @Mike With this solution the tiles get redrawn in the update interval. Nevertheless, in the network log, no new tile requests appear (thus, the same tile images as before are simply redrawn) even if I turn off HTTP chaching. Any idea where in the source the actual HTTP requests get called?